# Adding an HTML header to QNetworkReply

Tags: javascript, html, c++, ajax, qt

I have a subclassed QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply in order to handle custom AJAX requests from a JavaScript application. It mostly works, except it seems that my network replies are stripped of any headers.

I can verify that the `NetworkReply` returned by `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest` has the header set correctly, however I am not able to access it from JavaScript. Consider the code below:

In JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "test.php"); // fake url
xhr.responseType = "json";   
xhr.setRequestHeader("Test-Header", "42");   

xhr.onload = onXHRLoad;

xhr.send();
```

This is then retrieved inside `QNetworkAccessManager` and used to create a new `QNetworkReply` as follows:

```
NetworkReply *NetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData)
{
    if( request.url().host() == "test" )
    {
        NetworkReply* nr = new NetworkReply(request, outgoingData);

        if (nr->hasRawHeader("Test-Header"))
        {
            qDebug() << "[Qt] Sending Network Reply with Test-Header value: " << nr->rawHeader("Test-Header");
        }

        return nr;
    }

    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, request, outgoingData);
}
```

Inside `NetworkReply` constructor I retrieve the header value from the request and set it to the reply:

```
if (request.hasRawHeader("Test-Header"))
{        
    this->setRawHeader("Test-Header", request.rawHeader("Test-Header"));
}
```

I can verify this value is set correctly and the newly created reply does indeed have the header present, however when the JavaScripts receives the response the header is not present (while the data is):

```
function onXHRLoad(event) {
    var header = event.target.getResponseHeader("Test-Header"); // <- null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there are some extra steps required in `QNetworkReply` which were not documented anywhere. To get it working I needed to add the following to the constructor:

```
setRequest(request);
setUrl(request.url());
setOperation(operation);
```

This now works as expected.

You can see an example here:
https://code.google.com/p/htmapp/source/browse/#hg%2Ffrwk%2Fqt